# Render HTML (response of an aspx page) in Pega User Interface

Tags: pega

I am migrating an aspx application in to Pega which has heavy UI pages.

When I tried to render the respective HTML in the form/ user interface tab of PRPC, most of the UI controls did not render and have to do heavy Pega coding to make it work.

Are there any best practices or tools available to optimize UI design by converting aspx pages UI elements in to Pega?

I can understand out-of-the-box customized controls cannot be rendered unless there is a converter.

Answer (score 0):

No, how should that be possible? PRPC runs on a Java Application Server (Tomcat, Websphere or Weblogic) and thereby executes Java / JSP code - acting as a platform. The same way you can't just reuse php snippets in your Pega application.

In PRPC one UI rule type are sections. Sections are preferably auto generated, but you can choose to put in HTML code or even JSP code instead. There you could leverage the JavaScript frameworks included in PRPC or do includes on an iFrame basis. But you can't paste there php or aspx code since it won't be executed on the php resp. aspx environment.

Comment: I am trying to check if any Plug-ins or interpreters available in the market which can convert aspx or php before it hits underlying Java engine.